# AngularJS/HTML input week format error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to for user to choose week from a `input week` tag, but there is something bizarre qbout the format.

I've read that the format should be `yyyy-W##`, and I do this already, but angularJS still gives me this error:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-W51` to be a date
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2015-W51
```

and this is my tag:

```
<input type="week" ng-if="header.type==='week'" ng-model="entry[header.className]" ng-change="vos.fieldSelectionChanged(field_id,entry.record_id)"/>
```

So as you see, the `input type` is `week`, here, I'm using this tag inside of a `ng-repeat`, so I'm loading the data from the `entry[]` array, and the week loaded is `2015-W51`.

So please tell me what I'm doing wrong , is there a best practice using this tag with AngularJS?

Thanks !

**Edit 1 - more code**

I've found this:
http://codepen.io/empirefox/pen/MYyoao

It demonstrates how to use `input week` with a date, but the problem is that I don't have the data as dates.
And at the right part of the page, you have this :

```
$scope.value = new Date(2013, 0, 3);
```

Change it to this :

```
$scope.value = "2015-W20";
```

And it gives me the same error. So if we can solve this one, I think we can also solve the problem on my page.

Comment: Can you put more code ? The error and the code shared don't relate (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses native `Date` object to handle all its datetime-related `input`s, but unfortunately `Date` instances does not have any methods to handle week numbers. It would be the best solution to stick with `moment.js`.

Coercion from string to `ng-model`-enabled value (in controller etc.):

```
$scope.value = moment("2015-W20").toDate();
```

Coercion from `ng-model`-enabled value to string (in form submit handler etc.):

```
moment($scope.value).format("YYYY-[W]WW");   // returns "2015-W20"
```